# How do I change Bigcommerce quickview button display

Tags: bigcommerce

Hello I want to change my Quickview button text from "Quick View" to the product price of each item.
This is the shown query in the QuickViewJs.html

```
    ShowImageZoomer = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".QuickView").quickview({
        buttonText: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewButtonText%%",
        buttonColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewButtonColor%%",
        gradientColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewGradientColor%%",
        textColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewTextColor%%"
    });
});​
```

So I tried to replace the `%%GLOBAL_QuickViewButtonText%% to %%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%`,
I had confidence that this would definitely work and thought it would show the price of the product when I hover an item. However, it returned no value at all.

Any solutions? please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, I found out that %%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%% did not work because it is not a storewide GLOBAL value....

Comment: So I think I have to do something with the javascript itself..

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there are a few places quickview is called from, so search through all of the template files to make sure you've changed it in all of the places. You shouldn't have any trouble once it's set something like this:

```
$(".QuickView").quickview({
    buttonText: "Fast View", //Text changed on this line
    buttonColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewButtonColor%%",
    gradientColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewGradientColor%%",
    textColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewTextColor%%"
});
```

As far as colors go, I'm pretty sure most of their themes overwrite that with CSS these days.

Comment: @ChrisChoi you can select this answer as "correct" to resolve the question